# Merge the "drupal-7" and "drupal7" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

There is a question tagged [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7), on SO. The tag should probably merged with [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7) and made its synonym, to avoid somebody else tries to tag a question with [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7).

Comment: You have a score of 6 in the `drupal-7` tag, so you can propose `drupal7` as a synonym yourself, if you'd like.

Comment: I'd prefer to delete the tag and migrate all drups over to drupal.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) is now a synonym of [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7); the tags have been also merged.